# .htaccess url search and replace one string for another

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I need to change all URL's of one pattern to another:

http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_fireboard
to
http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_kunena

how would I substitute like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this somewhere appropriate in your htaccess file in your document root (probably before your joomla rules if you have any)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)option=com_fireboard(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /index.php?%1option=com_kunena%2 [L]
```

Comment: I'm afraid it had no effect, I get component not found standard joomla page. Unfortunately the site is running artio sef, which is extremely complicated. thanks for the thought though.